# UEFI hard drive access after ExitBootServices

Tags: uefi

I want to know how to access hard drive after `ExitBootServices()` without assembler code, but I can't get sufficient information from uefi spec (one reason is that I can't read English very much.) Can anyone tell me the way to control medium? Is it possible to take over functions from firmware after `BootServices()` called?

Comment: You need a driver up and running by the time you exit boot services. otherwise, assembler code ;)

Comment: hmm...I searched web and understood that recent devices are connected to PCIe host bridge.And I had a new question .  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50791215/9919708

Comment: here's the code I found on the web. According to this,assembler code is not necessary when using UEFI and ACPI.I'm very confused now... :-( https://github.com/Raphine/Raph_Kernel/blob/v0.1.0/source/kernel/dev/pci.cc#L48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it without writing your own storage, disk and partition drivers because once you call ExitBS() you become a sole owner of the initialized HW and can act as the first stage of OS kernel.

Writing storage drivers for your own OS kernel is out of scope for UEFI.

Comment: Thank you for answering:) Now I have set interrupts and made memory manager. And I desided to try to make xHC driver and USB driver.